# RNG creates 20 numbers between [9,10] a second. Use Poiss approx to find probability that it produces 4 numbers in [9.575,9.585] in 10 seconds

Tags: probability

RNG creates 20 numbers between [9,10] a second. Use Poiss approx to find probability that it produces 4 numbers in [9.575,9.585] in 10 seconds

So far I see the interval we want is 9.585-9.575=0.01 and since the distribution is uniform(this is given) we know that on average we'll get 0.01*20 of numbers in this interval a second. Then t=10 so using poiss approx, the MGF of Poiss is $e^{(e^t-1)\lambda}$ so that equals $e^{(e^{10}-1)*0.2}$, but I don't know how to approximate that it'll create 4 numbers in this time span.

Comment: The Moment Generating Function is overkill here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

- You expect an average of $0.01\times 20  = 0.2$ numbers in this interval in one second
- So how many do you expect in ten seconds?
- Using the Poisson distribution with $P(X=k)=\lambda^k e^{-\lambda} / k!$ and that expectation, what would the probability be of $4$ in ten seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Find $P(X=4)$ where $X\sim\mathsf{Poisson}(\lambda=0.01\times20=0.2)$.

Comment: I suspect that is for $1$ second rather than $10$ seconds